# When I use 'sed' command with -i (in-palce option), how can I see what is being or was changed on terminal?

Tags: shell, sed, printing

When using `sed` command with `-i` option (replace in-place), I wanna see what is being changed on terminal.

For example `test.txt` file,

```
abc 
def
```

When I've tried below,

```
$ sed -i 's/abc/ABC/g' test.txt
```

Nothing is printed.

Could someone help me to see what `sed` is replacing ?

Comment: There is no `verbose` mode in `sed`. Options that you have is, Either you validate the substitution (without `-i`) which will be printed on terminal. Otherwise use `-i .bak` to take backup your original file with `.bak` extension.

Comment: With bash: `diff <(< test.txt) <(sed 's/abc/ABC/g' test.txt); sed -i 's/abc/ABC/g' test.txt`? I suggest to create a function for this job.

Comment: `sed` can help you see what it is replacing.  You are telling it to not do that by passing `-i`.  Just stop using `-i`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a suffix with the `-i` switch to make a backup of the original, then run a `diff` program on both files:

```
sed -i.bak 's/abc/ABC/g' test.txt
diff test.txt.bak test.txt
```